# "ipython 2.4.1 has no extra feature 'all' "

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to setup mask_rcnn of matterport. When I try to setup the package, I receive the error " UnknownExtra: ipython 2.4.1 has no such extra feature 'all' ". I have created a separate environment and have the dependencies installed. My Ipython version is 7.13.0 . I do not have any further idea as to why I am receiving this error. I surfed the net but couldn't find much help. Understanding the cause of the problem can perhaps help solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you prepare your environment? Use anaconda, pip, or just install? How do you check your Ipython version? Use such as

```
import ipython
ipython.__version__
```

or just show it by `conda/pip list`.

When I use virtual environment by anaconda and install some package by pip, I had found sometimes they would give the different version. Make sure which environment you're using may helps you.